# Where is the openstack-install command?

Tags: openstack

I want to install openstack on a single computer for a test.
I want to understand how openstack works.
I have read several tutorials, saying it is possible to install openstack on a single computer. Those tutorials works on Ubuntu with apt.
There is a few apt-get/apt-add-repository commands to type, then

```
         apt-get install openstack
```

Then, the tutorials say I have to launch a command called openstack-install, but this command does not exists on my system.

I have installed exactly the same packages and I see screenshots of the tutorial.
Maybe it is an older version? (the tutorial is from 2015)

So how can I install openstack? I just want to select "single computer" and then have access to openstack web management console.

Comment: what version of Ubuntu are you installing on?

Comment: I have tried on ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64 and ubuntu-16.04.1-server-amd64

Comment: it appears there is a bug with this in 16.04... see this question http://askubuntu.com/a/785502/443498

Comment: yes i have read this thread and tried it. But i do not have "single computer" option

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at following links.

1. https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/
2. https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Packstack

As of now, Openstack installation cannot be done using something like *apt install openstack* or *yum install openstack*

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install OpenStack on single node, then you need to install devstack.
You need to clone devstack using command
`git clone https://git.openstack.org/openstack-dev/devstack`

devstack has the repository which intern installs OpenStack on single node.

Following link helps in deploying OpenStack on single node
https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/

Devstack can be used for testing only... It's not useful for production purpose.

Multinode OpenStack can be used for production purpose.

https://docs.openstack.org/newton/install-guide-ubuntu/environment.html

This is the official lab guide for installing OpenStack multinode Newton version...
You can follow the guide step by step.

Answer (score 0):

plz refer to official install docs: http://docs.openstack.org/

the problem is that is always targeted at latest release, if you want previous versions (which are not EOL), then refer to https://github.com/openstack/openstack-manuals and build it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For test and educational purpose you can install MicroStack, for more information follow this link.
[MicroStack Single-node Installation](https://microstack.run/docs/single-node)

if your instance doesn't connect to Internet use this 2 command:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.20.20.1/24 ! -d 10.20.20.1/24 -j MASQUERADE
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```